# Tabla de calificaciones del alumno en php y laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

**Creé una tabla para mostrar el nombre de los alumnos en vertical, el nombre de las materias en horizontal y la calificación de la asignatura del estudiante Tengo el siguiente código: esta es la parte del índice**

````
<form action="{{ route('Formatos.index') }}" method="GET">
    <select name="carrera_id">
        <option value="">Seleccione una carrera</option>
        @foreach ($carreras as $carrera)
            <option value="{{ $carrera->IdCarreras }}">{{ $carrera->NombreCarrera}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    <select name="Semestre_id">
        <option value="">Seleccione un semestre</option>
        @foreach ($semestres as $semestre)
            <option value="{{ $semestre->IdSemestres }}">{{ $semestre->Semestre}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    <select name="turno">
        <option value="">Seleccione un turno</option>
        <option value="Matutino">Matutino</option>
        <option value="Vespertino">Vespertino</option>
    </select>
    <select name="salon">
        <option value="">Seleccione un salon</option>
        <option value="Salon A">Salon A</option>
        <option value="Salon B">Salon B</option>
        <option value="Salon C">Salon C</option>
        <option value="Salon D">Salon D</option>
        <option value="Salon E">Salon E</option>
        <option value="Salon F">Salon F</option>
        <option value="Salon G">Salon G</option>
        <option value="Salon H">Salon H</option>
 </select>
    <select name="U1">
        <option value="U1">Seleccione una unidad</option>
            <option value="U1">U1</option>
            <option value="U2">U2</option>
            <option value="U3">U3</option>
            <option value="U4">U4</option>
            <option value="U5">U5</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Mostrar</button>
</form>
                        
                          @csrf
                            <table id="tabla_datos" class="table table-striped mt-2">
                                <thead style="background-color:#6777ef"> 
                                    <tr>
                                        <td rowspan="2" > ```


``@if ($materias->count() > 0)
    <table style=" width: 1180px;">
        <thead>
            <tr style=" width: 110px;">
            <td style="background-color: gray; color:#fff; width: 80px;"> Asignatura</td>
                @foreach ($materias as $materia)
                    <th style="background-color: #18316B; color:#fff; width: 90px;">{{ $materia->NombreMateria }}</th>
                @endforeach
                <th style="background-color: #18316B; color:#fff;width: 80px;"  colspan="6">Observaciones</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <td style="background-color: gray; color:#fff;"> Unidades</td>
            <td  style="background-color: #18316B; color:#fff;">
              <select id = "grade-selector" class="form-control" style="width: 80px;">
                <option value="U1">U1</option>
                <option value="U2">U2</option>
                <option value="U3">U3</option>
                <option value="U4">U4</option>
                <option value="U5">U5</option>
              </select>
            </td> 
            <td style="background-color: #18316B; color:#fff;">
              <select  id = "grade-selector2" class=" form-control" style="width: 80px;" >
                <option value="U1">U1</option>
                <option value="U2">U2</option>
                <option value="U3">U3</option>
                <option value="U4">U4</option>
                <option value="U5">U5</option>
              </select>
            </td> 
            <td style="background-color: #18316B; color:#fff;">
              <select id="grade-selector3" class=" form-control" style="width: 80px;">
                <option value="U1">U1</option>
                <option value="U2">U2</option>
                <option value="U3">U3</option>
                <option value="U4">U4</option>
                <option value="U5">U5</option>
              </select>
            </td> 
            <td style="background-color: #18316B; color:#fff;">
              <select id = "grade-selector4" class=" form-control" style="width: 80px;">
                <option value="U1">U1</option>
                <option value="U2">U2</option>
                <option value="U3">U3</option>
                <option value="U4">U4</option>
                <option value="U5">U5</option>
              </select>
            </td> 
            <td style="background-color: #18316B; color:#fff;">
              <select id = "grade-selector5" class=" form-control" style="width: 80px;">
                <option value="U1">U1</option>
                <option value="U2">U2</option>
                <option value="U3">U3</option>
                <option value="U4">U4</option>
                <option value="U5">U5</option>
              </select>
            </td> 
            <td style="background-color: #18316B; color:#fff;">
              <select id = "grade-selector6" class=" form-control" style="width: 80px;">
                <option value="U1">U1</option>
                <option value="U2">U2</option>
                <option value="U3">U3</option>
                <option value="U4">U4</option>
                <option value="U5">U5</option>
              </select>
            </td> 
            <td style="background-color: #18316B; color:#fff; width: 1000px;"> </td>
            </tr>
@endif
@if ($alumnos->count() > 0)
    <table>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($alumnos as $index => $alumno)
                @if (isset($estudiantes[$index]) && isset($calificaciones[$index]))
                    <tr>
                        <td  style="background-color: #fff; color:black; width: 110px; text-align: center;">  {{ $estudiantes[$index]->name }}</td>
                        @foreach ($calificaciones as $calificacion)
                        <td class="grade-cell U1" style="background-color: #fff; color:black; width: 180px; text-align: center;">{{ $calificacion->U1 }}</td>
                        @endforeach
                        @foreach ($calificaciones as $calificacion)
                        <td class="grade-cell2 U2" style="background-color: #fff; color:black; width: 180px; text-align: center;">{{ $calificacion->U2 }}</td>
                        @endforeach
                        @foreach ($calificaciones as $calificacion)
                        <td class="grade-cell U3" style="background-color: #fff; color:black; width: 180px; text-align: center;">{{ $calificacion->U3 }}</td>
                        @endforeach
                        <td style="background-color: #fff; color:black; width: 130px;">
                            <textarea id="observaciones-{{ $index }}" name="observaciones[]" rows="3" cols="25">{{ $formatos[$alumno->Alumno_id]->observaciones ?? '' }}</textarea>
                            <button onclick="guardarComentarios({{ $alumno->Alumno_id }})">Guardar</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    
                @endif
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
        
    </table>
@endif
 @section('scripts')
                                            <script>
                                                function printTable()
            {
                var table = document.getElementById("tabla_datos");

                var printWindow = document.createElement('iframe');
                printWindow.style.position = 'absolute';
                printWindow.style.top = '-10000px';
                printWindow.style.left = '-10000px';

                document.body.appendChild(printWindow);

                printWindow.contentDocument.write('<html><head><title>Imprimir tabla</title>');
                printWindow.contentDocument.write('</head><body>');
                printWindow.contentDocument.write(table.outerHTML);
                printWindow.contentDocument.write('</body></html>');

                printWindow.contentWindow.print();

                setTimeout(function () 
                { 
                    document.body.removeChild(printWindow);
                }, 1000);
            }
    function guardarComentarios(alumnoId) {
        var comentarios = document.getElementById('comentarios_' + alumnoId).value;

        // Realiza una petición AJAX para guardar los comentarios en el backend
        // Puedes utilizar jQuery o la librería nativa fetch() para realizar la petición

        // Ejemplo con jQuery:
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/Formatos/agregarComentarios',
            data: {
                alumno_id: alumnoId,
                comentarios: comentarios
            },
            success: function(response) {
                alert('Comentarios guardados exitosamente');
            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert('Error al guardar los comentarios');
            }
        });
    }
    $('#grade-selector').on('change', function() {
        var selectedGrade = $(this).val();

        // Hide all grade cells
        $('.grade-cell').hide();
        $('.grade-cell2').hide();

        // Show the selected grade cell
        $('.' + selectedGrade).show();
    });
    $('#grade-selector').trigger('change'); 
                                            </script>
                                            @endsection
````

*Este es el controller of Calificacion. He creado la función index para mostrar el nombre del alumno y de la materia, y la calificación del alumno y de la materia. En la vista de index, creé una lista desplegable donde puedo elegir la carrera, el semestre, el salon y el turno, y dentro de la tabla creé seis listas desplegables donde las unidades de cada materia dentro del cuadro de la materia**

```
class FormatoController extends Controller
{
    // $data = Process::with('user')->findOrFail(Auth::id()); 
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

     public function index(Request $request)
{
    $query = Calificacion::select('Alumno_id')->get();
    $carreras = Carrera::all();
    $comentarios = Formato::all();
    $calificaciones = Calificacion::all();
    $maestros = Maestro::all();
    $turnos = Calificacion::all();
    $salones = Calificacion::all();
    $semestres = Semestre::all();
    $estudiantes = Calificacion::join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'calificacions.Alumno_id')
    ->select('users.name')
    ->distinct()
    ->get();

    

    // Obtener la lista de alumnos distintos
    $alumnos = Calificacion::select('Alumno_id')->distinct()->get();

    // Obtener la lista de materias relacionadas con las calificaciones
    $calificaciones = Calificacion::first();
    $calificaciones = Calificacion::with('materias', 'calificaciones')->get();
    $calificaciones = Calificacion::select('Alumno_id', 'U1', 'Materia_id', 'U2', 'U3','U4','U5','U6','U7', 'U8', 'U9', 'U10','U11','U12')->distinct()->get();

    // Obtener los formatos relacionados con los alumnos
    $formatos = Formato::whereIn('nombre', $alumnos->pluck('Alumno_id'))->get()->keyBy('Alumno_id');

    // Obtener los filtros de búsqued
    $semestreId = $request->input('Semestre_id');
    $maestroId = $request-> input('Maestro_id');
    $materiaId = $request -> input('Materia_id');
    $turnoId = $request -> input('turno');
    $salonId = $request -> input('salon');
    $calificacionId = $request->input('U1');
    $calificacionId = $request->input('U2');
    $calificacionId = $request->input('U3');
    $calificacionId = $request->input('U4');
    $calificacionId = $request->input('U5');
    $calificacionId = $request->input('U6');
    $calificacionId = $request->input('U7');
    $calificacionId = $request->input('U8');
    $calificacionId = $request->input('U9');
    $calificacionId = $request->input('U10');
    $calificacionId = $request->input('U11');
    $calificacionId = $request->input('U12');

     // Filtrar por carrera seleccionada
    if (request()->has('carrera_id')) {
        $carreraId = request('carrera_id');
        $alumnos = Calificacion::where('Carrera_id', $carreraId)->get(); // Obtener los alumnos de la carrera seleccionada
        $materias = Materia::where('carrera_id', $carreraId)->get(); // Obtener las materias de la carrera seleccionada


        if ($semestreId) {
            $materias = $materias->where('semestre_id', $semestreId);
        }
        if ($calificacionId) {
            $calificaciones = $calificaciones->where('U1','U2','U3','U4','U5','U6','U7', 'U8', 'U9', 'U10','U11','U12', $calificacionId);
            $calificaciones= Calificacion::where('Materia_id', $calificacionId)
            ->where('U1', $calificacionId)
            ->get();

            foreach ($calificaciones as $calificacion) {
                $calificacion->U1;
                $calificacion->U2;
                $calificacion->U3;
                $calificacion->U4;
                $calificacion->U5;
            }
            $materias= Calificacion::where('Materia_id', $calificacionId)
            ->where('U1', $calificacionId)
            ->get();

            $materias = $materias->where('U1','U2','U3','U4','U5','U6','U7', 'U8', 'U9', 'U10','U11','U12', $calificacionId);
            

            $alumnos = $alumnos->where('U1','U2','U3','U4','U5','U6','U7', 'U8', 'U9', 'U10','U11','U12', $calificacionId);
            
        }
        if ($turnoId) {
            $semestres = $semestres->where('turno', $turnoId);
            $materias = $materias->where('turno', $turnoId);
            $alumnos = $alumnos->where('turno', $turnoId);
            $alumnos= Calificacion::where('turno', $turnoId)
            ->get();
            $semestres= Calificacion::where('turno', $turnoId)
            ->get();
            $materias= Calificacion::where('turno', $turnoId)
            ->get();
        }
        if ($salonId) {
            $semestres = $semestres->where('salon', $salonId);
            $alumnos= Calificacion::where('salon', $salonId)
            ->get();
            $semestres= Calificacion::where('salon', $salonId)
            ->get();
            $materias= Calificacion::where('salon', $salonId)
            ->get();
        
            $materias = $materias->where('salon', $salonId);
            $alumnos = $alumnos->where('salon', $salonId);
        }

        if ($maestroId)
        {
            $maestros = $maestros->where('Maestro_id', $maestroId);
        }


    } else {
        $alumnos = collect(); // Crear una colección vacía de alumnos
        $materias = collect(); // Crear una colección vacía de materias
        $semestres = collect();
        $calificaciones = collect();// Crear una colección vacía de calificaciones
        $maestros = collect();
        $calificacionesPorUnidad = [];
    }
    


    $calificaciones = Calificacion::with('materias')->get();
    $calificaciones->each(function ($calificacion) {
        $alumno = optional(Calificacion::find($calificacion->Alumno_id));
        $calificacion->alummos = $alumno->Alumno_id ?? null;
        $calificacion->materias = optional(Materia::find($calificacion->Materia_id))->NombreMateria;
    });
    // Filter calificaciones by selected units
    
    $formatos = Formato::paginate(10);
    return view('Formatos.index',compact('carreras', 'alumnos', 'materias', 'formatos', 'estudiantes', 'semestres', 'calificaciones', 'maestros', 'turnos', 'salones'));
}
```

**Route**
`Route::get('/Formatos',[ FormatoController::class, 'index'])->name('Formatos.index');`

**Cuando elijo, por ejemplo, U1, solo funciona en una lista desplegable y solo muestra como este**

[image]

**Cuando tengo la siguiente base de datos en phpmyadmin**

[image]

**Me serviria de ayuda como puedo arreglar esto. Ya que quiero que cuando en otra lista despleganle, escoga U2 o U3 de otra materia, muestre la calificacion del alumno en la materia**